# Last couple hundred blocks of syncing?

Tags: synchronization

I notice that when I leave my computer off for a couple hours or something and then restart and have to resync the chain that it always slows down considerably near around 200 blocks behind the "highest known block".

Does this last, most recent syncing of blocks take longer because the full state is being downloaded, while previous blocks' states are not fully downloaded?

Answer (score 2):

Final syncing of the last ~200 blocks does not complete until all states have been synced.  You are correct at the end the blocks stop downloading only the states sync until they completely catch up then syncing of the blocks will finish.  Depending on your system it can be stuck on the last ~200 blocks for several hours.  As of yesterday i think there were something like 27+ million states.  you can check the progress of the state and block syncing by entering the java console with

```
geth attach
```

and once in the console using this command:

```
eth.syncing
```

Comment: Actually, the geth console is a JavaScript environment, not a Java environment. Very different.

Comment: Sorry for my typing error; you are absolutely correct.  I think it doesn't change the answer to the question asked.  Great MEANINGFUL input.  Thx for contributing.  Keep up the great work!!

Comment: You're quite welcome. Thank you for such a helpful and insightful answer!